# Panel data and regression analysis

Tags: regression, panel-data

I am doing my bachelor thesis and I want to analyse how capital structure affect profitability. I have panel data and I am unsure what kind of regression should I use. If I am only interested in variables and their coeficients, could I use multiple linear regression? Added a snip of how my data look.
[image]

Comment: Since you have panel data, why not use a some model (e.g. with firm and year fixed effects) that takes the structure into account: $y_{i,t}=\beta_0+\gamma_t+\delta_i+\beta_1x_{i,t}+\varepsilon_{i,t}$? I have tried asking ChatGPT for R code for such a model, and it delivered this: `library(plm); data <- read.csv("data.csv"); pdata <- pdata.frame(data, index=c("firm_id", "year")); model <- plm(Y ~ X, data=pdata, index=c("firm_id", "year"), model="within")`.